# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Android App

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I working on an Android Application but I'm facing a problem which is : `Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;` I've tried some things like removing the `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` file, adding : **import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;**, but now I'm facing another problem which is in :

`adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());` it tells me that **The constructor AdRequest() is not visible**, Please Help Me, Guys, I'm new in android developing.

And thanks to every one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were using the Admob Ads SDK, but since you have now included the **Google Play Services** library, the interface is slightly different.

For this particular error, you need to use the [AdRequest.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html) class, i.e.

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .build();
```

I suggest you take a look at the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/play-migration).